# Wamp virtual domain subfolders wrong port

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

Hopefully a quick question that I cant find any answer to. I've set up a virtual host in wamp successfully on port 8080 (since iis has occupied 80) but all resources and folders my site location still tries to access through port 80.

This my setup (following guide http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757)

in httpd-vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/dev/frontend"
    ServerName test.local
    ServerAlias *.test.local
    <Directory  "C:/dev/frontend">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    php_flag display_errors Off
    php_flag log_errors On

    php_value max_upload_size 40M
    php_value max_execution_time 120
    php_value error_log "C:/wamp/logs/example_com_phperror.log"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    ErrorLog "logs/errors.log"
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Syntax running oki in the `httpd -t` check in the bin folder. In my httpd.conf its also set to Listen on port 8080.

My host file should also be setup right:

```
127.0.0.1       test.local
::1             test.local
```

But sub folders and assets are still going to the wrong port:

```
 http://test.local:80/assets/css/bootstrap.css
 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\assets\css\bootstrap.css
```

So what am I missing?

Comment: Try starting with changing `ServerAlias *test.local` to `ServerAlias test.local`

Comment: I am also fairly sure that tutorial suggests putting the VH definition for localhost first in your list of VHOSTS, and never using `Allow from all` on localhost

Comment: Removing or adding the asterisk does nothing, to my knowledge its for allowing subdomains, etc book.test.local.. And moving the localhost definition up or down doesnt matter. My localhost is working fine, showing wamp homepage fine.

Comment: Only fishy thing I can find is that trying to activate the Virtual host menu in wamp with adding ";WAMPVHOSTSUBMENU" doesnt work

Comment: Sorry, but `*.test.local` is correct syntax and not `*test.local`

Comment: Just out of interest, what version of WAMPServer are you running?

Comment: Ah of course! Missed a dot.
This would be WampServer 2.5

Comment: @RiggsFolly No that was never my issue, the problem is my resources go to the wrong path etc **test.local:8080/css/main.css** is trying to go to **test.local:80/css/main.css**.

Comment: So show use the html `<link...` that you use to include the css

Comment: Also when you setup the vhosts to use 8080 did you also change httpd.conf to also use 8080